# Using pylint to display Error and Warnings simultaneously

Tags: python-2.7, warnings, indentation, pylint

I am trying to use pylint to display warning and errors , 
i want all warnings and error to be displayed at the same time ,  i.e 
when i do:

```
pylint pylint_1.py -rn -d=R,C
```

it should siplay me all warning and errors , 
but instead what happens is when my program has some errors (indentation error)
it will only show the erros , warning are suppressed . 
also if program has indenation errors at two places it will show only the first error .

Here is my sample file :

```
import string
def somefun():
    shift = 3
    choice = raw_input("would you like to encode or decode?")
    word = (raw_input("Please enter text"))
    count_un = 10
    letters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
    encoded = ''
    if choice == "encode":
        for letter in word:
            if letter == ' ':
                encoded = encoded + ' '
            else:
                x = letters.index(letter) + shift
                encoded=encoded + letters[x]
    if choice == "decode":
        for letter in word:
            if letter == ' ':
                encoded = encoded + ' '
            else:
                x = letters.index(letter) - shift
                 encoded = encoded + letters[x]
    print encoded
```

output :
When only warning is their :

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module pylint_1
W:  6, 4: Unused variable 'count_un' (unused-variable)
```

When i do a indentation error:

```
No config file found, using default configu
************* Module pylint_1
E: 22, 0: unexpected indent (syntax-error)
```

Clearly ,it's visible warning is suppressed when error is there

I am new to pylint , please let me know if my effort is correct ,
i.e what i am trying is possible or not .

Is it possible to display all the warnings and errors in one go .??

Comment: For the case where there's a `syntax-error` I don't think it's possible, as pylint can't parse your code at all.

Comment: @TheCompiler is right, if there is some syntax error, pylint can't do any further processing as it's not able to get an AST representation of the source code, hence you only see that error.

Comment: That's fine . only errors , but it shows only single error not all the errors